# concatenate two parts of a word in a list using iterator

Tags: python, string, list, iterator, concatenation

I need to concatenate certain words that appear separated in a list of words, such as `"computer"` (below). These words appear separated in the list due to line breaks and I want to fix this.

`lst=['love','friend', 'apple', 'com', 'puter']`

the expected result is:

`lst=['love','friend', 'apple', 'computer']`

My code doesn't work. Can anyone help me to do that?

the code I am trying is:

```
from collections import defaultdict
import enchant
import string
words=['love', 'friend', 'car', 'apple', 
'com', 'puter', 'vi']
myit = iter(words)
dic=enchant.Dict('en_UK')
lst=[]

errors=[]

for i in words:

   if  dic.check(i) is True:

      lst.append(i)
   if dic.check(i) is False:

      a= i + next(myit)

   if dic.check(a) is True:

      lst.append(a)

   else:

     continue



print (lst)`
```

Comment: How do you know which words are to be concatenated?

Comment: "These words appear separated in the list due to line breaks and I want to fix this"-- it might be easier and certainly cleaner to go back a step and fix the buggy line break code

Comment: 'My code doesn't work'  - can you  be more specific? If you didn't get the expected output, what did you get? If you got an error, please include the complete error traceback in your question

Comment: @Chris_Rands, I can't fix that because these words were separated when I exported from a PDF to a .txt file. The words that were separated by line breaks by a hyphen in the PDF are now separated without a Hyphen in the .txt file

Comment: @ThierryLathuille. I think there is something wrong when I try to concatenate the two parts of the words with 'i + next(myit)"

Comment: @Austin the words that appear separated in the list, such as "computer"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notwithstanding the fact that this method is not very robust (you would miss "ham-burger", for example), the main error was that you didn't loop on the iterator, but on the list itself. Here is a corrected version.

Note that I renamed the variables to give them more expressive names, and I replaced the dictionnary check by a simple `word in dic` with a sample vocabulary - the module you import is not part of the standard library, which make your code as-is difficult to run for us who don't have it.

```
dic = {'love', 'friend', 'car', 'apple', 
       'computer', 'banana'}

words=['love', 'friend', 'car', 'apple', 'com', 'puter', 'vi']
words_it = iter(words)

valid_words = []

for word in words_it:
    if word in dic:
        valid_words.append(word)
    else:
        try:
            concacenated = word + next(words_it)
            if concacenated in dic:
                valid_words.append(concacenated)
        except StopIteration:
            pass

print (valid_words)
# ['love', 'friend', 'car', 'apple', 'computer']
```

You need the `try ... except` part in case the last word of the list is not in the dictionnary, as `next()` will raise a `StopIteration` in this case.

Answer (score 1):

The main problem with your code is that you are, on the one hand, iterating `words` in the `for` loop and, on the other hand, through the iterator `myit`. These two iterations are independent, so you cannot use `next(myit)` within your loop to get the word after `i` (also, if `i` is the last word there would be no next word). On the other hand, your problem can be complicated by the fact that there may be split words with parts that are too in the dictionary (e.g. `printable` is a word, but so are `print` and `able`).

Assuming a simple scenario where split word parts are never in the dictionary, I think this algorithm could work better for you:

```
import enchant

words = ['love', 'friend', 'car', 'apple', 'com', 'puter', 'vi']
myit = iter(words)
dic = enchant.Dict('en_UK')
lst = []
# The word that you are currently considering
current = ''
for i in words:
    # Add the next word
    current += i
    # If the current word is in the dictionary
    if dic.check(current):
        # Add it to the list
        lst.append(current)
        # Clear the current word
        current = ''
    # If the word is not in the dictionary we keep adding words to current

print(lst)
```

Comment: Ok. But the code does not concatenate the separated words in the list and this is my objective

Comment: @NadiaSantos This code should put the concatenated words in `lst` (you keep adding parts of the word in `current` until you get a full word that is in the dictionary). However, if it is not working for you, could you show the result that you are getting? (I cannot install pyenchant in my machine unfortunately). Is it possible that enchant considers `com` to be a valid word? (see ["com" definition at dictionary.com](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/com)).